# Does InstanceId exist in StatelessServiceInitializationParameters?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

Per [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.statelessserviceinitializationparameters.aspx) from 2016, StatelessServiceInitializationParameters is supposed to have a property called InstanceId.

I am attempting to find this property, but it seems that it may have been obsoleted?[image]

**How do we get the instanceid for StatelessServiceInitializationParameters to get the instanceid/replicaid?**

Comment: Well, don't you need an instance of the class first? The method is not static according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.serviceinitializationparameters.initializationdata.aspx) you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `base.Context.InstanceId` as follows:

```
internal sealed class CalculatorService : StatelessService, ICalculatorService
{
    public CalculatorService(StatelessServiceContext serviceContext) : base(serviceContext)
    {

    }

    public Task<string> Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(string.Format("Instance{0} returns: {1}", base.Context.InstanceId, a + b));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [StatelesServiceContext.InstanceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.statelessservicecontext.instanceid?view=servicefabric-5.5.216#System_Fabric_StatelessServiceContext_InstanceId) property. This is available as [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.runtime.statelessservice.context?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceFabric_Services_Runtime_StatelessService_Context) property in StatelessService class.